# Processing - loadFont not able to locate any files

Tags: processing

I have the following code:

```java
class Terminal {
  PFont font;

  Terminal() {
    font = loadFont("Serif-48.vlw");
  }
}
```

It gives the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load font Serif-48.vlw. Make sure the font has been copied to the data folder of your sketch." even when I have verified that the font is already in the correct folder. The example sketches that come with Processing that use fonts in the exact same way work perfectly fine.

I'm using Processing 1.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.1 with the packaged version of Java (1.6.0_26-b03-383).

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried you're class and if I create the font it works fine.
Try deleting your current vlw file and going to **Tools > Create Font...** in
the Processing IDE to recreate Serif-48 (should be the default one).

My current setup is Processing 2.0a1 on OSX 10.6.8.

If the samples work fine, it's clearly something wrong with that particular sketch.
Try recreating the font as I mentioned above, and if that doesn't work, either
create a new sketch from scratch and test the font first, then continue bringing your
other classes/functions in, either save a version of a sample that works and change
it into the sketch you need.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can install the file onto the machine as a ttf. And call it that way with createFont.

Example:

```
// declare exfont to be of the data type PFont
PFont exfont;

// createFont(name, size, smooth, charset)
exfont = createFont("nameofthefontfileonyourmachine", 60, true);
textFont(exfont);
```

one other problem you may run into with this method. if you are trying to use a .otf on Windows 7 ... you will need to convert and install the file as a .ttf for Processing to recognize it and use it in the sketch.